# I make big structures look marvellous

Tags: riddle, word, limerick

> As an object of beauty, I’m fabulous
>   Take a closer look, I’m nebulous
>   I can be rolled all around
>   Or found beneath the ground
>   I make big structures look marvellous

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you are

> marble

As an object of beauty, I’m fabulous

> Marble is pretty

Take a closer look, I’m nebulous

> Not sure... though perhaps, like all matter, there is "lots" of space between atoms.  @MatthewJensen's suggestion that there can be nebulous looking cloudy patterns in marble seems like a good suggestion!

I can be rolled all around

> Marbles can be rolled

Or found beneath the ground

> Marble is mined from the ground

I make big structures look marvellous

> Marble structures do indeed look great

Comment: Perhaps for the second sentence rot13(znal zneoyrf unir n arohyn-ybbxvat funcr jvguva gur tynff)

Comment: @MatthewJensen makes sense!  i edited that in.

Comment: I want another clue to the effect of rot13(jvgubhg zr lbh'yy tb penml), but not sure how it would fit into the verse...